# different error documents for different hosts listening on the same port

Tags: apache2

I have an apache2 with this similar configuration

```
<VirtualHost IP:8080>
        ServerName IP:8080
        DocumentRoot /var/www/x1
        ErrorDocument 400 https://IP:8080
        SSLEngine on
        ....
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost example.com:8080>
        ServerName example.com:8080
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ErrorDocument 400 https://example.com:8080
        SSLEngine on
        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

the problem is that when I access http:/example.com:8080 the error document that redirect is the one of the ip. What could be wrong?

I have try to put it inside the Directory directive but doesn't work either.

Comment: What version of apache are you running? before Apache 2.3.11 you would need `NameVirtualHost` set to handle domain name virtual hosts with SSL/TLS <https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost>

Comment: Plus, can I ask - why are you not just returning a specific page `ErrorDocument 400 /error_pages/error-400.html ` as error document rather than referring back to same address?

Comment: I have apache 2.4 and what I'm trying to do is redirect http to https on the same port

Answer (score 0):

OK. After you have explained more precisely your problem, I will presume that you want to serve HTTPS content on a non-standard port (here it will be 8443) :

```
Listen IP:8080
Listen IP:8443 https

Listen example.com:8080
Listen example.com:8443 https

<VirtualHost IP:8080>
        ServerName IP
        Redirect "/" "https://IP:8443/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost IP:8443>
        ServerName IP
        DocumentRoot /var/www/x1
        SSLEngine on
        ....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example.com:8080>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect "/" "https://example.com:8443/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost example.com:8443>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        SSLEngine on
        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

This is based on the [example found in the Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect). Since, in this example, I was not using a standard port for HTTPS, I had to make some adjustments using the [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive also described in the Apache documentation.

Comment: Hello thanks for answering but that is not what I am trying to do, what I am trying to do is that when entering http:/example.com:8080 it redirects to httpS:/example.com:8080 and if I enter http:/IP:8080 it redirects to httpS:/IP:8080, x1 is just an example document root name for the default virtual host for that port, and IP my public ip address.
Currently the failure is that if I enter http:/example.com:8080
redirects to https:/IP:8080. I hope this time I have explained myself better.
Also if you know of a better way to redirect http to https on the same port it would also help me.

Comment: OK. I have modified my answer but I think you should modify your original question with the precision you have given here.